# Executing statements after a successful asynchronous request in a try/catch block

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch

I am trying to understand why a console.log statement will not output to the terminal after a successful asynchronous network request. I understand why it would not execute if the request fails, since the execution would jump to the catch block. However, after completing a successful request I see no trace of the logging statement. I have the following code:

```
function processRequest (url, res) {
    return axios.get(url).then(response => {
        res.send({status: 'PASS', message: `${response.status}, on ${url}`});
    });
}

app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    let response;
    try {
        response = await processRequest(someValidURL, res);
        console.log('after request'); //this statement does not show up after successful request
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

}
```

In order to minimize this post, I did not include the require statements for express and the axios libraries as well as the express set-up code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are returning a response from within `processRequest` which means your request processing is finished there and the response is sent.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you should do it like this

```
function processRequest (url) {
    return axios.get(url);
}

app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    let response;
    try {
        response = await processRequest(someValidURL);
        console.log('after request', response);
        res.send({status: 'PASS', message: `${response.status}, on ${url}`}); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
        res.send({status: 'ERROR'});
    }
}
```